# Converting a sum type to BuiltinByteString

Tags: plutus

I have a type defined as follows:

`data A = A1 | B2 | A3 deriving (Show, Eq)`

Is it possible to convert it to and from `BuiltinByteString` without explicitly having functions as such:

```
convertToBuiltInByteString :: A-> BuiltinByteString
convertToBuiltInByteString A1 = "A1"
convertToBuiltInByteString B2 = "B2"
convertToBuiltInByteString A3 = "A3"

fromBuiltInByteString :: BuiltinByteString -> A
fromBuiltInByteString "A1" = A1
fromBuiltInByteString "B2" = B2
fromBuiltInByteString "A3" = A3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also derive a `Read` instance, then it should be possible to use `show` and `read` to covert to and from `String` and there is likely a way of converting from `String` to and from `BuiltinByteString`.